# How to configure P4V to display time in 24h format?

Tags: perforce, p4v

How to configure P4V to display time in 24h format?

I think I have searched everywhere in the software, but didn't find any related settings.

I cannot bare the format anymore, especially the `12:00 AM`. It's killing me. Please can anybody help me out?

[image]

Comment: In `Edit -> Preferences -> Display -> Dates` there is an option called `perforce standard (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss)`. It works in some places. But the `File History` table still goes 12h format.

Comment: Sounds like a bug!  If you have a paid license you can report that to Perforce support; it's probably an easy fix (like just a matter of not passing some formatting flag to that particular Qt widget).

Answer (score 2):

In `Edit -> Preferences -> Display -> Dates`, set to `perforce standard (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss)`, and restart your P4V and click `Refresh`.